# Restricting svn access for some IP

Tags: linux, svn, amazon-web-services

I am setting up svn in my amazon linux server. I want to restrict my project access through browser. Like https://test.com/.svn/text-base/Copy of test.php.svn-base  this link is now accessible through browser . I want that no one can read,write or execute this file. Is this possible? If possible please help me how can I do this? It is better if I restrict all Ip except me.Please help.

Comment: `text-base` and the fact that you have `.svn` sounds like it is a *working copy* and not a server repository.

Comment: yes it is but I did not want that anyone see my working copy as well as server repository

Answer (score 2):

You can do this through apache configuration

eg:

```
<LocationMatch "^/svn/repo/project/*">
Order Deny,Allow 
Deny from all 
Allow from **YOUR IP ADDRESS** 
</LocationMatch>
```